# Pipenv: "An error occurred while installing cytoolz" when trying to install web3 (python3.8-dev is installed)

Tags: python, python-3.8, pipenv, web3py

I'm trying to install web3 in my pipenv environment and it fails when trying to install cytoolz. I already tried installing python3.8-dev (as the environment requires 3.8) and libssl-dev is also already installed.

First it says

> An error occurred while installing cytoolz==0.10.0 ; implementation_name == 'cpython' --hash=sha256:ed9f6a07c2bac70d6c597df360d0666d11d2adc90141d54c5c2db08b380a4fac! Will try again.

It then proceeds to try to install it again and then outputs a log error message

Comment: "Fixed" it by moving to Python3.7

Comment: Is that really a fix if your goal was to use Python3.7?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be you installing Xcode Developer Tools. This is due to the fact that it will install C compiler which is a key dependency for cytoolz. That should sort out your issue once and for all.